# Can you legally dynamic_cast to non-polymorphic base class of a polymorphic class

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329645/1277769), the following scenario came up:

```
#include <cassert>

struct A {};

struct B { virtual ~B(){} };

struct AA{};
template <class T>
struct C : A, T {};

int main()
{
  B * b = new C<B>;
  AA * aa = new C<AA>;
  assert(dynamic_cast<A*>(b));
  assert(dynamic_cast<A*>(aa)); //this line doesn't compile, as expected
}
```

On g++ 4.8.4 (Ubuntu), this compiles and the assert passes.  My question is, is that really legal?  I feel like you shouldn't be able to `dynamic_cast` to a non-polymorphic class at all, but I freely admit that I'm not an expert in what's happening here.

When I tried the opposite direction:

```
dynamic_cast<B*>((A*)(new C<B>));
```

it fails to compile, stating that "source type is not polymorphic".  I feel like that's a clue, but it still seems a stretch to find the non-polymorphic base class that belongs to a class that the current pointer is a base of (did that sentence make sense?).

Comment: Upvoted as promised.

Comment: @Bathsheba It's a bit discouraging that the whole time I was writing this question SO was giving me a warning that the title seems subjective and this question will likely be closed :S :P

Comment: Odd isn't it? Yet so much junk slips through the net.

Comment: @SirGuy Maybe "you" is a trigger word?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can.

As the C++ standard says in §5.2.7/5 about the expression `dynamic_cast<T>(v)`:

> If `T` is “pointer to *cv1* `B`” and `v` has type “pointer to *cv2* `D`” such that
>   `B` is a base class of `D`, the result is a pointer to the unique `B`
>   subobject of the `D` object pointed to by `v`.

An example is given, too:

> ```
> struct B { };
> struct D : B { };
> void foo(D* dp) {
>   B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(dp); // equivalent to B* bp = dp;
> }
> ```

As you can see, polymorphic classes are clearly not the only use case of `dynamic_cast` permitted by the standard.

By the way, cppreference [explains it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) in less standardese language:

> If *new_type* is a pointer or reference to Base, and the type of
>   *expression* is a pointer or reference to Derived, where Base is a
>   unique, accessible base class of Derived, the result is a pointer or
>   reference to the Base class subobject within the Derived object
>   pointed or identified by *expression*. (Note: an implicit cast and
>   static_cast can perform this conversion as well.)

Comment: There's no reason this _wouldn't_ work, as by definition, any compiler that knows the source type must know that it has the destination type as a base.

Comment: @underscore_d: Of course. Nevertheless, seeing `dynamic_cast` used for this should raise an eyebrow and *might* indicate a logical error in the code.

Comment: In my example, `dynamic_cast` is given a pointer to `B` and then has to find the derived class `C<B>` and then finds _its_ base class `A` for the `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: Looking at a draft of the standard, §5.2.7/8.1 seems to be the passage that I'm looking for, not /5.  The difference is that since the input is polymorphic, the most derived type is considered (`C<B>` in my example) and its base classes are scanned for a match.